# SoapClient error in my laravel project while I have installed it

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I am getting error - Class 'SoapClient' not found in my laravel project.
My code is as follow:

```
        $client = new \SoapClient($url , ['encoding' => 'UTF-8']);
```

I installed php7.1-soap and I checked my server. I uncommented the extension=php_soap.dll at /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

When I hit php -m command I can see soap package. 
I don't know what I have not done yet. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you restart the apache? In terminal ‘php -m’ is using the php.ini of the cli and not the “cgi”

Comment: Yes I did, And I also checked php -i and it shows SOAP functions and all are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `SoapClient` aliases on `config/app.php`. For using something like this `\DB, \Validator ...`, you should add this to aliases.

I hope this will help.

Comment: What should I add to config/app.php? I thought that soapClient is build-in.

Comment: I think you should use like this ` $client = new SoapClient($url , ['encoding' => 'UTF-8']);` You IDE will suggest class name for use this class. If this not working, Can you run `composer dump-autoload` command.

Comment: What should I put in app.php?

Comment: Can you send me your used package name for SoapClient ?

Comment: I used this: use SoapClient;

Comment: I tried this on my local. I install `php7.2-soap` then I enabled this both apache and php conf under `/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini` then restart my computer and It works. Example usage, `$client = new SoapClient($url, ['encoding' => 'UTF-8']);`

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem.
I had several php on my server and apparently, soap was installed on php 5 while my php version was 7.0
I removed the old version and installed soap for php 7.0 and problem solved. Thanks for everyone's response.